# AWS API Gateway read: connection reset by peer error

Tags: go, tcp, httpconnection, aws-api-gateway

We have deployed few of our micro services into AWS kubernetes cluster. The high level message flow of the application architecture is as follows.

Client Application -> AWS API Gateway -> Istio Proxy -> Micro Service

While doing some performance testing from a client application(Written in GoLang) with concurrent load of around 20 requests per seconds for different micro services(All micro services have same host and different path like https://aws-api-gateway.com/service1,  https://aws-api-gateway.com/service2) we are intermittently encountering the following error in client application.

```
Error while signing Post "https://aws-api-gateway/service1/v1/client/payload/sign": read tcp 192.168.1.77:51734->54.xxx.xxx.xx:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

When error occurs, it occurs in groups, like we see around 10 request are rejected by "read: connection reset by peer".

The client application have the http connection pool with MaxIdleConns=100 and MaxConnsPerHost=100

We have confirmed that endpoints doesn't have any rate limiting setup(If the rate limiting is exceeded, the error will be http response code)

What would be the possible root cause of this error.

Answer (score -2):

I'd say that first of all, you need to find out where this errors are happening in your infrastructure. You can use monitoring tools like Amazon CloudWatch (https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/), Prometheus, etc. Once you identify where is the problem, then you can try to find out the cause.